# Javascript Excel Sheet

Tags: javascript, excel, html-parsing

i have an HTML page with some graphs on it. What i want to do is write an on-load javascript function, that will read values from an excel sheet, store them in variables and use those on the html page. My question is are there any javascript APIs that deal with excel sheets as in parse values from excel sheet cells??

Comment: Whole lot of questions here.

1. You know you cant get at a file on a user's local machine so they will have to upload to the server?

2. Much depends if this is an xls or an xlsx...

Comment: And a weird idea ! Why don't you upload the spreadsheet to the server side and read it with a decent library supported by your server-side language ?

Comment: Why don't you "save as: xml" and then parse the data to retrive the information you want.

Comment: Uh, okay its xlsx.......and yes the excel sheet will be on the server as well, local to the html page, it'll be updated as and when required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote an xlsx parser in javascript. https://gist.github.com/trevordixon/3375836

```
/*
    Relies on jQuery, underscore.js, Async.js (https://github.com/caolan/async), and zip.js (http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js).
    Tested only in Chrome on OS X.

    Call xlsxParser.parse(file) where file is an instance of File. For example (untested):

    document.ondrop = function(e) {
        var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
        excelParser.parse(file).then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }, function(err) {
            console.log('error', err);
        });
    }
*/

xlsxParser = (function() {
    function extractFiles(file) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        zip.createReader(new zip.BlobReader(file), function(reader) {
            reader.getEntries(function(entries) {
                async.reduce(entries, {}, function(memo, entry, done) {
                    var files = ['xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml', 'xl/sharedStrings.xml'];
                    if (files.indexOf(entry.filename) == -1) return done(null, memo);

                    entry.getData(new zip.TextWriter(), function(data) {
                        memo[entry.filename.split('/').pop()] = data;
                        done(null, memo);
                    });
                }, function(err, files) {
                    if (err) deferred.reject(err);
                    else deferred.resolve(files);
                });
            });
        }, function(error) { deferred.reject(error); });

        return deferred.promise();
    }

    function extractData(files) {
        var sheet = $(files['sheet1.xml']),
            strings = $(files['sharedStrings.xml']),
            data = [];

        var colToInt = function(col) {
            var letters = ["", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
            var col = $.trim(col).split('');

            var n = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
                n *= 26;
                n += letters.indexOf(col[i]);
            }

            return n;
        };

        var Cell = function(cell) {
            cell = cell.split(/([0-9]+)/);
            this.row = parseInt(cell[1]);
            this.column = colToInt(cell[0]);
        };

        var d = sheet.find('dimension').attr('ref').split(':');
        d = _.map(d, function(v) { return new Cell(v); });

        var cols = d[1].column - d[0].column + 1,
            rows = d[1].row - d[0].row + 1;

        _(rows).times(function() {
            var _row = [];
            _(cols).times(function() { _row.push(''); });
            data.push(_row);
        });

        sheet.find('sheetData row c').each(function(i, c) {
            var $cell = $(c),
                cell = new Cell($cell.attr('r')),
                type = $cell.attr('t'),
                value = $cell.find('v').text();

            if (type == 's') value = strings.find('si t').eq(parseInt(value)).text();

            data[cell.row - d[0].row][cell.column - d[0].column] = value;
        });

        return data;
    }

    return {
        parse: function(file) {
            return extractFiles(file).pipe(function(files) {
                return extractData(files);
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try making use of ActiveXObject to read the data from excel. There are various utility methods.

Check out this link.

http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/javascriptexamples/javascript-get-excel-file-data.shtml

Comment: yeah but activeX can be used only for IE right? I want something on Safari